# How do I change the border color of an input text when user types in

Tags: javascript, html, css

the border color will be depending on the current typed value.
I've tried to change the className of the input text using javascript when onkeypress event happens,

```
element.className= 'recordInputEdited';
```

however, it cannot get rid of the :focus style,  the new class is visible until the text box loses focus. any idea?

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: post a fiddle for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/GQSsw/

HTML:

```
<input id="element" />
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('element').onkeydown = function() {
    this.className= 'edited';
}
```

CSS:

```
input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input:focus {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

input.edited {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: this seems to work,  but not in my environment, I will need to dig deeper , it looks like another css piece is avoiding to change the class right away in the onkeydown method.

Comment: You could also try `input.edited{border: 1px solid yellow !important}`

Answer (score 1):

with css you simply can:

```
input:focus {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I am not asking how to set the :focus style.

Comment: hm, some code from you would be usefull. For easy Dom manipulations and event handling in Javascript you could use jQuery.